# Trying to limit a list in C

Tags: c

right now i'm trying to build a simple program as my homework for college, this was supposed to be a simple code but i'm learning c just now and i'm having a really bad time trying to learn it, anyways, this code should be able to add to add, remove, show and clear some numbers on the console, a list(i dont know if it's called that way in english), but 1 thing that i can't do and i have been researching and tryed to figure out is in how to put a limit on this list, exactly 20 numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *prox;
};
typedef struct node Fila;

int t;

int menu(void);
void opcao(Fila *f, int op);
void inicia(Fila *f);
int vazia(Fila *f);
Fila *aloca();
void insere(Fila *f);
Fila *retira(Fila *f);
void exibe(Fila *f);
void libera(Fila *f);
void liberar_mem(Fila *f);

int main(void)
{
    Fila *f = (Fila *)malloc(sizeof(Fila));
    if (!f)
    {
        printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        inicia(f);
        int opt;

        do
        {
            opt = menu();
            opcao(f, opt);
        } while (opt);

        free(f);
        return 0;
    }
}

int menu(void)
{
    int opt;

    printf("Escolha a opcao\n");
    printf("0. Sair\n");
    printf("1. Zerar solicitacoes\n");
    printf("2. Exibir solicitacoes\n");
    printf("3. Inserir o numero da solicitacao\n");
    printf("4. Remover solicitacao\n");
    printf("Opcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &opt);

    return opt;
}

void opcao(Fila *f, int op)
{
    Fila *tmp;
    switch (op)
    {
    case 0:
        liberar_mem(f);
        break;

    case 1:
        libera(f);
        inicia(f);
        break;

    case 2:
        exibe(f);
        break;

    case 3:
        insere(f);
        break;

    case 4:
        tmp = retira(f);
        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Solicitacao removida: %3d\n\n", tmp->num);
            free(tmp);
        }
        break;

    default:
        printf("Comando invalido\n\n");
    }
}

void inicia(Fila *f)
{
    f->prox = NULL;
    t = 0;
}

int vazia(Fila *f)
{
    if (f->prox == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

Fila *aloca()
{
    Fila *novo = (Fila *)malloc(sizeof(Fila));
    if (!novo)
    {
        printf("Sem memoria disponivel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Insira o numero da solicitacao: ");
        scanf("%d", &novo->num);
        return novo;
    }
}

void insere(Fila *f)
{
    Fila *novo = aloca();
    novo->prox = NULL;

    if (vazia(f))
        f->prox = novo;
    else
    {
        Fila *tmp = f->prox;

        while (tmp->prox != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->prox;

        tmp->prox = novo;
    }
    t++;
}

Fila *retira(Fila *f)
{
    if (f->prox == NULL)
    {
        printf("Lista de solicitacoes ja esta vazia\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Fila *tmp = f->prox;
        f->prox = tmp->prox;
        t--;
        return tmp;
    }
}

void libera(Fila *f)
{
    if (f->prox == NULL)
    {
        printf("Lista de solicitacoes ja esta vazia\n");
        Fila *proxNode, *atual;
        atual = f->prox;

        while (atual != NULL)
        {
            proxNode = atual->prox;
            free(atual);
            atual = proxNode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!vazia(f))
        {
            Fila *proxNode, *atual;
            atual = f->prox;

            while (atual != NULL)
            {
                proxNode = atual->prox;
                free(atual);
                atual = proxNode;
            }
        }
    }
}

void exibe(Fila *f)
{
    if (vazia(f))
    {
        printf("Nenhuma solicitacao cadastrada!\n\n");
        return;
    }

    Fila *tmp;
    tmp = f->prox;
    printf("Fila :");
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%5d", tmp->num);
        tmp = tmp->prox;
    }
    printf("\n        ");
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < t; count++)
        printf("  ^  ");
    printf("\nOrdem:");
    for (count = 0; count < t; count++)
        printf("%5d", count + 1);

    printf("\n\n");
}

void liberar_mem(Fila *FILA)
{
    if (!vazia(FILA))
    {
        Fila *proxNode, *atual;

        atual = FILA->prox;
        while (atual != NULL)
        {
            proxNode = atual->prox;
            free(atual);
            atual = proxNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "put a limit on this list, exactly 20 numbers". Can't you just have a counter that increments on add and decrements on remove? And if it reaches the limit an add will return "sorry, full"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a global variable that keeps track of the current length of the list and return an error message when someone tries to expand the list beyond the limit.

However, while global variables are fine for simple programs, it's considered good style for larger programs to rely upon them as little as possible.

Therefore, I'd recommend using a "list header" object.  For example,

```
#define MAX_LIST_LENGTH 20

struct list_header {
    Fila *start_of_list;
    unsigned int current_length;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but how i'm supposed to use this list_header on my code? i'm quite confused about where to put it, and how to use it, if it's possible could you help me?

Comment: Sure, no problem.  With all of your functions above which modify `Fila` objects, you would instead pass them a pointer to a `struct list_header`.  Take a look at this example: https://pastebin.com/jEAFeCkC